# Google Apps Script editor not launching

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor

From this morning I have no possibility to edit scripts. My existing script link to a spreadsheet continue to work but when I try to edit them or to edit a new one , I only get a shaded upper bar, and no possibility to use it.

Last times one of my scripts was getting some errors, is it possible that google "ban" me from using script due to too much memory using?

Thanks in advance,

david

Comment: see https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4339

Answer (score 6):

I used Chrome Incognito mode as a temporary fix.
Hopefully, this works for you as well.

Answer (score 4):

Switch you drive locale settings to English and it will work. This is a temporary workaround to use until they fix the bug. [see issue 4339](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4339)

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I was still signed into another account despite the UI suggesting otherwise. Restarting the browser and checking who you are logged in as in Drive (and potentially signing the incorrect user out) fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score -3):

Exactly. I was signed with different account without permits. Request access to the Sheet with full access without restrictions and it will work :)